Is it safe to wrap KVO in continuation
Is it safe to wrap KVO inside a continuation like this? My concern is that if play is called again before the existing KVO callback is invoked, the  observer would be deinit'ed and callback never invoked, leaving the continuation to hang
var observer: NSKeyValueObservation?
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?

func play(asset: AVURLAsset) async throws {
  playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

  let readyToPlay = try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
    observer = playerItem?.observe(\.status, changeHandler: { item, _ in
      swtich item.status:
        case .readyToPlay: continuation.resume(returning: true)
        default: continuation.resume(throwing: item.error!)
    }
  }
  ...
}


Your concern is correct, and should be easy to demonstrate with a small test program. (AVPlayerItem shouldn't be needed; you could test with any NSObject subclass.)
